# Receiving EMail in Android App

Tags: android, email

I already found a lot of stuff matching my question, but I am not able to use it.
My application communicates with other applications via LAN, but now I want them to communicate via Email too.

My problem: How can I receive email in app e.g. from gmail or others?

I already found this working code for sending:
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

I read it would be easy to modify this code so that it can receive emails, But I have no idea how to do that. Please help or give me some hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this out....

```
Properties props = new Properties();
//IMAPS protocol
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
//Set host address
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imaps.gmail.com");
//Set specified port
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
//Using SSL
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
Session imapSession = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", usr, password);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] msgs =inbox.getMessages()
```